# How to count column 1 and return result in column 2 for specific ID numbers for current row and above?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to figure out how to count each instance an ID is in the ID # column for the current row and above.  Then display the count in the Count column.

For example:

- Row 2: 15404 is the first time it is displayed so the count is 1.
- Row 3: 15404 is the second time it is diplayed so the count is 2.
- Row 4: 15404 is the second time it is diplayed so the count is 3.
- Row 5: 99999 is the second time it is diplayed so the count is 1.
- Row 6: 55512 is the second time it is diplayed so the count is 1.
- Row 7: 99999 is the second time it is diplayed so the count is 2.

| ID # | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 15404 | 1 |
| 15404 | 2 |
| 15404 | 3 |
| 99999 | 1 |
| 55512 | 1 |
| 99999 | 2 |
| 34489 | 1 |
| 15404 | 4 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or another option, placed anywhere on row 2:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,ROW(A$2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A)))
```

It could be placed anywhere on row 1 with this format:

```
={"Header label text"; ArrayFormula(countifs(A2:A,A2:A,ROW(A$2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A)))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)
```

Then drag the formula.

**What it does?**

- We locked both row and column index of COUNTIF() start range using `$` which will start at `A1`
- We locked the column index of COUNTIF() end range using `$` which will increment from `A1` to `A8`

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to wrap that in an array formula so I don't have to drag down.  Users can add templates at any time.  I'd hate to have to keep checking and dragging the formula down when new data is added.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A:B; "select A,count(B) where A is not null group by A label count(B)''")
```

Comment: I received the following error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: ADD_COL_TO_GROUP_BY_OR_AGG: A

Comment: @Charity fixed try now